# How to use two different argument captors in one test method?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a problem using captors to test two separate calls of the same method, but with different argument type.

I provided a code sample of what I'm trying to do here - basically I want to verify if certain method was called twice but with different type arguments using two separate captors, and then call some assertions on captured objects.

```
public class Foo {
}

public class Bar {
}

public interface MyClient {
  void doSomething(Object obj);
}

public class MyService {
    private MyClient client;

    void doSomething() {
        client.doSomething(new Foo());
        client.doSomething(new Bar());
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService testObj;

    @Mock
    private MyClient myClient;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Foo> fooCaptor;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Bar> barCaptor;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        testObj.doSomething();

        verify(myClient).doSomething(fooCaptor.capture());
        // ...do something with fooCaptor

        verify(myClient).doSomething(barCaptor.capture());
        // ...do something with barCaptor
    }
}
```

I'd expect this test would pass as is, because captors specify argument types, so shouldn't this work same as `ArgumentMatchers.any(Foo.class)` etc?

Currently I'm getting TooManyActualInvocations - 2 instead of 1.

How do we handle such cases? I don't like the idea of using one  captor and then cast the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine the captors with the `isA` matcher using the `and` operator from the `AdditionalMatchers` package.

```
import static org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.and;

// ...

verify(myClient).doSomething(and(isA(Foo.class), fooCaptor));
verify(myClient).doSomething(and(isA(Bar.class), barCaptor));
```

Comment: Captor is not a matcher, I guess you meant `verify(myClient).doSomething(and(isA(Foo.class), fooCaptor.capture()))` etc, but still Mockito is unable to handle this situation when you try to call getValue: `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
No argument value was captured!
You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...`